# Categorical description of equivalence relation generated by a relation?

Tags: category-theory, equivalence-relations

The notion of an equivalence relation generated by a relation is widespread and useful. How can one categorically describe it?

Comment: It's interesting that the answers so far differ in level of abstraction and are so different despite being categorical. Goldblatt's book has yet a 3rd representation of equivalence relation by composing commutative triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider the category ${\mathscr C}$ of sets which come equipped with a relation, and with morphisms in ${\mathscr C}$ being relation preserving maps of sets. Then the full subcategory of sets equipped with an *equivalence* relation (called *setoids*) is [reflective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory) in ${\mathscr C}$, with the left adjoint of the inclusion sending an object $(X,\sim)$ to $(X,\simeq)$ where $\simeq$ is the equivalence relation generated by $\sim$.

Comment: Hanno, what if equivalence is replaced by other types of relations as per my comment to Andreas?

Answer (score 5):

A binary relation $R$ on a set $X$ is a subset of $X\times X$, represented categorically by a monomorphism $R\to X\times X$. By the categorical definition of products, that amounts to a (jointly monic) pair of morphisms $R\to X$.  Take the coequalizer $p:X\to Q$ of that pair.  Then take the kernel pair of $p$ (i.e., the pullback of $p$ along itself). That's a pair of morphisms $E\to X$, so you can combine them to constitute a morphism $E\to X\times X$. That morphism is monic, and the binary relation on $X$ that it represents is the equivalence relation generated by the original $R$.

Comment: Isn't the last sentence still true for relations that are not equivalences, eg order, tolerance, apartness etc. If so how can these be distinguished via this approach?

Comment: @alancalvitti The last sentence begins with the words "That morphism", referring to the morphism $E\to X\times X$ just mentioned at the end of the preceding sentence.  That morphism, as I defined it, is always an equivalence.  If you start with another sort of relation $R\to X\times X$, like an order, tolerance, apartness, etc., and apply the construction in my answer, you'll get an equivalence $E\to X\times X$.

Comment: The transitive closure of a tolerance is an equivalence, but how can this closure of an order, which is antisymmetric, be an equivalence?

Comment: @alancalvitti The transitive closure of an order is not an equivalence; it is the order itself, because orders are transitive.   On the other hand, what I described in my answer is an equivalence.

Comment: Understood: *E* can't be a closure of *R*. Is there an algorithm to compute *E* given finite *R*?

Comment: @alancalvitti Sure, provided $X$ is also finite (so that $E$ will be finite). Adjoin to $R$ all the pairs $(y,x)$ for $(x,y)\in R$ and all the pairs $(x,x)$ for $x\in X$. Then take the transitive closure of this enlarged relation.

Comment: You're describing the reflexive, symmetric and transitive closure of *R*. So isn't *E* is the smallest equivalence relation containing *R*?  my previous comment (re closure) is false. By the way, symmetric `S` and transitive `T` closure don't commute - the image of `S*T` includes that of `T*S`.

Comment: @alancalvitti Of course, I'm describing the reflexive, symmetric, transitive closure of $R$; that's what the question is about. And of course symmetrization doesn't generally commute with transitive closure; that's why I symmetrized first and then took the transitive closure.  So I don't see the point of your comment.

Comment: I should have highlighted *smallest* and *containing*, which are implicit in your answer, to clarify. You also wrote "*the* equivalence relation generated by.." - meaning unique. Is reflexive closure of *R* post-composed with `T*S` also an equivalence? (I haven't checked). On this theme, shouldn't we also look for the *largest* equivalence *conained* in *R*? After all, you gave diagram constructions that could be dualized.

Comment: If you reflexivize, then transitivize, and then symmetrize, you won't generally get an equivalence relation. Also, given $R$, there usually isn't a largest equivalence relation included in $R$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.